# hg push hangs after modify file in repository

Tags: mercurial

I have a Mercurial repository where some Python scripts are used by a web server. I have only one branch and a nested git repository. Everything was right. Now here's the issue: In order to conduct debugs and tests, I finally make changes directly to the file in the repository and then report modification locally when it's done. Since, whenever I tried to push something (after a commit, of course) it hangs and I can't do anything. The last message it displays is `searching for changes`.

I also tried `--debug`. This is what I get:

```
nested: git --version
nested: git for-each-ref --format %(objectname) %(rename)
nested: git merge-base b8e9bd80c6d0ec8e003033e2d2f36f336c994f7f 7697f69d09ab4e9b3f6e0d83232675c91c45777e
query 1; heads
sending batch command
searching for changes
all remote heads known locally
preparing listkeys for "phases"
sending listkeys command
received listkey for "phases": 15 bytes
checking for updated bookmarks
preparing listkeys for "bookmarks"
sending listkeys command
received listkey for "bookmarks": 0 bytes
sending branchmap command
sending branchmap command
preparing listkeys for "bookmarks"
sending listkeys command
received listkey for "bookmarks": 0 bytes
1 changesets found
list of changesets:
caa866293415a14a273676bc2a7d37617084cdf2
bundle2-output-bundle: "HG20", 4 parts total
bundle2-output-part: "replycaps" 155 bytes payload
bundle2-output-part: "check:heads" streamed payload
bundle2-output-part: "changegroup" (params: 1 mandatory) streamed payload
bundle2-output-part: "pushkey" (params: 4 mandatory) empty payload
sending unbundle command
sending 751 bytes
```

How can I do to make to force push or revert my change in the repository?

Optional: Is it possible to make temporary changes in the repository for tests and debugs and make everything still work?

Comment: Hello, you need to explain better your setup. How many repositories do you have? Where is the master? What is the error message when you do "hg push" ? I doubt that hg push can hang.

Comment: Hello, I have just put more details. It is a one-branch repository with a nested git repository. I also provided the --debug output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved my issue.

In the .hg directory of the repository at the server, I found a wlock file that block any push commands. I just deleted it. I also delete the modified file so the push brings it back properly.

Problem solved!

Comment: (Wow, I saved myself again by finding this on Google. Thanks past-me!)